# What could be the origin of this polychrome wooden statue?

Tags: middle-ages, identification, renaissance

I purchased this statue at an estate sale. I initially thought it was depicting a Wise Man from a nativity scene, but the back is flat indicating it was against a wall.

Now I'm thinking it was depicting an Old Testament king, maybe from the Carolingian ages. I've seen termite damage like this on French sculptures before. I think it's made of walnut wood. It was painted, but now only faint traces remain.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Where was it purchased?

Comment: Is there any evidence it is old/genuine?

Comment: I don't suppose there's any kind of maker's mark on the underside?

Comment: This is definitely not Carolingian, not even medieval. My guess is that this is some of the saint Popes. Right hand was probably originally risen in blessing gesture. The crown is based on tiara of the type that can be seen on sculptures from 17th century.  The fashion is late renaissance at the earliest, but can be also from 19th century. Technique is not exactly masterful, so I can imagine it was taken from an altar in some smaller village church. Oversized head may suggest it was located relatively high on the altar.(if sculptor was skilled enough to do it intentionally)

Comment: I would take any answer here with a massive grain of salt. Get a professional appraisal, preferably in person. With a bit of luck you can find someone to do it free.

Comment: @BrianZ: agreed. We may give some hints, but it's worth having that piece estimated by a professional. Some do it for free (I remember going to [Drouot](https://drouot.com/en) some decades ago seeking help for some Louis XIV signature on papers. Appointment needed. FWIW: papers were authentic piece of history, signature was worthless as most of them were made by secretaries at that time. Few hundreds $$$ and not more. Costed me the trip to Paris, and a day, not more)

Comment: I do appreciate all the comments.    To answer some of the questions:…. I purchased the statue at an estate sale for $275.  It seems completely genuine to me considering the faded paint, the termite damage, the overall presence of the thing.  Why would someone put such effort into faking such an object of relatively little value?, I ask myself.   There is no signature or and other indication of provenance.

Comment: A professional appraisal sounds like a wise next step.   I’ll report back my findings.

Comment: It may not be fake in the sense of an intentional forgery, but it may have been made in the 19th or 20th century in a more or less historical style. So it may be genuine but not genuine in the sense of being very old.

Answer (score 3):

As far as I can tell by the style, this statue would be at least post 14th-century, maybe even later. The head seems wearing a tiara <sup>[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tdL53.png)</sup>, meaning it could be a pope. I've seen some of these (very similar) in small churches in France and Belgium ([Flanders](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flanders)). Most of them are from local artists.

The coat/cape is held in the front with a piece of jewelry like bishops or pope  (or even kings) wore.

The statue is missing its arms, which would probably hold its own symbols or the ones symbolizing the power of the pope, one or both hands. One hand can also hold a type of [crosier](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Crosier) while the other is blessing.

You can see a similar statue <sup>[2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dTNt0.png)</sup> of a [16th century carved, polychrome painted and gilt wooden figure of a bishop (Southern Netherlands, Flanders)](https://www.coronariauctions.com/en/auction-may-2021-asian-european-and-islamic-arts/4809-a-carved-polychrome-painted-and-gilt-wooden-figure-of-a-bishop-southern-netherlands-flanders-16th-c) (probably of a better craftmanship though).

If we can't be really sure about what it is, we may eventually eliminate what it's probably not: a merovingian/carolingian statue.

Comment: Thank you.  Your comments make a lot of sense.  I’ve seen many other statues posed as you described on my travels visiting the churches of Europe.